# Restoring layout in DevExpress PivotGridControl in my WinForms project does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, devexpress, pivot-grid

I used following code to save and restore `DevExpress PivotGridControl V7.2` layout:

```
//save layout
var fileName = string.Format(@"c:\pivot.xml");
pivotGridControl.SaveLayoutToXml(fileName);

//restore layout
var fileName = string.Format(@"c:\pivot.xml");
pivotGridControl.ForceInitialize();
pivotGridControl.RestoreLayoutFromXml(fileName);
```

But after running restore code, the layout doesn't change!
Has my code any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Devexpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/), following code, solved the problem:

```
pivotGridControl.OptionsLayout.Columns.RemoveOldColumns = false;

pivotGridControl.RetrieveFields();            
foreach (PivotGridField field in pivotGridControl.Fields) {
    field.Name = "field" + field.FieldName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with devexpress enough. But I suggest if you did not get a good answer. You can ask the question as a Ticket in the devexpress support section
[Devxpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)